# Postgres Aggregating conditional sum

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to sum-aggregate conditional products for total weight of an order (I hope that makes sense).  I get error:

> ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested
>   LINE 6:        , SUM ( CASE  WHEN pc.type = 'TEES' THEN (SUM (opd.qt...

This is query excerpt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         o.work_order_number dn
       , SUM(opd.qty) units
       , SUM (CASE  WHEN pc.type = 'TEES' THEN (SUM (opd.qty) * .75)
            WHEN pc.type = 'JERSEYS' THEN (SUM (opd.qty) * 1.5)
        END) AS weight
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT o.work_order_number dn 
     , SUM(opd.qty) units 
     , SUM ( opd.qty * CASE pc.type 
                           WHEN 'TEES' THEN 0.75 
                           WHEN 'JERSEYS' THEN 1.5 
                       END ) AS weight
FROM ...
GROUP BY o.work_order_number
```

Answer (score 4):

Well what you can do is nest your select statement E.g

```
select sum(weight),sum(etc) 
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT o.work_order_number dn 
                 , (opd.qty) units 
                 , ( CASE WHEN pc.type = 'TEES' THEN ((opd.qty) * .75) 
                          WHEN pc.type = 'JERSEYS' THEN ((opd.qty) * 1.5) END) AS weight)
).
```

So first select statement handles your case statement and second select statement sums up your fields.